# How can I figure out which version of Python first has a given Fix?

Tags: python, release-management, issue-tracking

Reading the Python-Future docs for unicode [1], I found out about a fix to Python 2.7 [2]. It is resolved as accepted and closed.

How can I find out in which python version it will appear? May I assume since we just had a release in December [3] that it will be in the next one? I see that the detailed changelogs [6] contain ticket id's for each item, even though release notes [7] do not.

I have had the same question previously with older tickets [4], eg [5]. It seems that the final shipped-in point version is not listed in the bugbase. I hope this is a good place to ask this question! I have been wanting to help out on the python code base, so this will help me get my feet wet.

---

1. X.Should I import unicode_literals? — Python-Future documentation
   http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html
2. Fix Suggested 2004-11-14 01:36, incorporated 2014-01-05 22:14 ; ; ;  X.Issue 1065986: Fix pydoc crashing on unicode strings - Python tracker
   http://bugs.python.org/issue1065986#msg207403
3. Python 2.7.9, Release Date: 2014-12-10, a bugfix version also includes... The entirety of Python 3.4's ssl module has been backported ; ; ; ; ;  X.Python Release Python 2.7.9 | Python.org
   https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/
4. Easy tickets that are closed, sorted by Update date ; ; ; ; ; ; ;  X.List of issues - Python tracker
   http://bugs.python.org/issue?%40search_text=&ignore=file%3Acontent&title=&%40columns=title&id=&%40columns=id&stage=&creation=&creator=&activity=&%40columns=activity&%40sort=activity&actor=&nosy=&type=&components=&versions=&dependencies=&assignee=&keywords=6&%40columns=keywords&priority=&status=2&%40columns=status&resolution=&nosy_count=&message_count=&%40group=&%40pagesize=50&%40startwith=0&%40sortdir=on&%40queryname=easy+fixed+tix&%40old-queryname=&%40action=search
5. Example; ; ; ; ; ;  X.Issue 21971: Index and update turtledemo doc. - Python tracker
   http://bugs.python.org/issue21971
6. Changelog for all versions, latest on top ; https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v2.7.9/Misc/NEWS
7. Point version pre/release notes have summaries instead of details like [6]; Examples are ; https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/ and https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279rc1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a change is committed to a particular branch, it should appear in the next point release after that date.

I checked the for the first version of Python 2.7 released after the date the fix was checked in. That's release 2.7.7. Here is a link to the announcement of that release:

https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.7/

And if you follow the `numerous bugfixes`, you get this:

https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/f89216059edf/Misc/NEWS

The same file from the 2.7.9 release also lists the fix under release 2.7.7.

https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/v2.7.9/Misc/NEWS